# What configuration do I need to set or change after migrating data to Version 1.0.0/1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, migrate, apache-iotdb, iotdb

May I ask how to migrate the data of Apache IoTDB from Version 0.13.2 to Version 1.0.0 or 1.1.0? I checked the previous answers and know that I may need to use "load" command, but I'm still a little confused. Does this mean to directly load the tsfile data of Version 0.13.2 to Version 1.0.0/1.1.0? After I do that, are there any configurations that I need to set or change?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly load all tsfiles from Version 0.13.2 to Version 1.0.0. After starting Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.0, you can execute statement like load '/User/Desktop/data', verify='true', onSuccess='none'. If you have enough space to store all historical data, remember to set `onSuccess='none'`, so that the historical tsfile in IoTDB will not be deleted.